# How do i load images locally from a folder using thumbor

Tags: thumbor

Suppose I have a image (sydney.jpg) which is at location `/home/emirates/flight/static/images`. In my thumbor configuration I have enabled the below

```
FILE_STORAGE_ROOT_PATH = '/home/emirates/flight/static/images'
```

But when I try to use it like so `http://localhost:8888/unsafe/300x200/home/emirates/flight/static/images/sydney.jpg` then it does not work. What seems to be the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Enable the file loader and give Thumbor the correct path:

```
FILE_LOADER_ROOT_PATH=/home/emirates/flight/static/images
LOADER=thumbor.loaders.file_loader
```

The correct URL to your local Thumbor server for that image should be:

`http://localhost:8888/unsafe/300x200/sydney.jpg`

*Remark: in my experience Thumbor uses port 8000 by default. So you might want to check that. Your question does not specify the type of error your ran into.*

Answer (score 0):

Good morning fear_matrix,

Have you tried this?

```
http://localhost:8888/home/emirates/flight/static/images/sydney.jpg
```

Thanks